# Using Riemann’s Theorem on removable singularities to show that limit exists

Tags: limits, holomorphic-functions, singularity

I try to solve the following exercise:

Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $f,g$ holomorphic functions on $G \setminus\{z_0\}$ for some $z_0 \in G$. Assume that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_o} f(z) = 0 = \lim_{z\rightarrow z_o} g(z)$ and that the limit $$c:=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$$ exists. Prove that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=c.$$

I have to use Riemann’s Theorem on removable singularities here. 
My attempt was to show that if $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$ exists, then there exists a neighborhood around $0$ such that $f,g$ are bounded and then I can use Riemann's Theorem to show that the functions can be extended. But I think this does not help me. Moreover I tried to use L'Hospital but I do not even know if this works in $\mathbb{C}$.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You can apply l'Hospital rule once you know $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z) $ exists. For showing that you need Riemann's theorem on removable singularities (whose proof is by looking at $h(z) = z^2 f(z)$ holomorphic on $0 < |z| < r$ and since $\lim_{z \to 0} h'(z) = 0$ it is holomorphic and hence analytic on $|z| < r$)

Comment: But why do I need that $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}f'(z)$ exists? For l'Hospital's rule I actually only need $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} g(z) = 0$ and that the limit $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$ exists. But these conditions are fulfilled, so why do I need the existence of $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}f'(z)$?

Comment: you need to show that $g'(z) \ne 0$ on $0< |z| < \epsilon$, or equivalently that $f'(z) \ne 0$ on $0< |z| < \epsilon$, or that $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$ exists. That's why you should prove that $f(z)$ is analytic first